# Limiting behaviour of a real Möbius sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, dynamical-systems

Consider the fractional linear transformation of the real variable $t$, transformation
$$f(t)=\frac{at+b}{ct+d}$$
where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$. Define $t_{n+1}=f(t_n)$ where $t_0\in\mathbb{R}$. There are plenty of references indicating how this sequence behaves when $f$ has either two distinct fixed points $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ and when $f$ has one fixed point $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. However, I couldn't find anything that indicates the behaviour (however nasty) when $f$ has no fixed point. Is there any reference that indicates how this is analysis might proceed?

I'm actually thinking of $f$ as an automorphism of the circle (or equivalently the real projective line). I was wondering if there is a result such as $\{t_n\}$ is dense in the circle (except for certain combinations of $a,b,c,d$ that give cyclic behaviour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theorem**: A real fractional-linear transformation without real fixed points is conjugate to a real rotation, and therefore either has finite order (in which case every orbit is finite) or infinite order (in which case each orbit is dense in the real projective line).

*Proof*: The eigenvalues of a fixed-point free real Möbius transformation $f$ are complex conjugates, say $\alpha \pm \beta i$. The real Möbius transformation $T(z) = (z - \alpha)/\beta$ sends $\alpha \pm \beta i$ to $\pm i$, so the real Möbius transformation $g = T \circ f \circ T^{-1}$ fixes $\pm i$, and is therefore a rotation of the Riemann sphere, which restricts to a rotation of the real projective line through an angle $\theta$. The order of $g$, and hence of $f$, if finite if and only if $\theta$ is a rational multiple of $2\pi$.

If $f$ has infinite order, the orbits of $f$ in the *complex* projective line are dense subsets of [Apollonian circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_circles) (with two exceptions, the complex fixed points of $f$).

Comment: This is a great response. My only query is: why is a mapping that fixes $\pm i$ necessarily a rotation of the Riemann sphere?

Comment: It's crucial also that $g$ is _real_, i.e., maps the real axis to itself. Geometrically, $g$ fixes a pair of antipodes ($\pm i$) and stabilizes the equator (the real projective line); what can it be but a rotation of the Riemann sphere? :) Algebraically, one might compose $g$ with the rotation $R$ fixing $\pm i$ and sending $g(0)$ to $0$; such an $R$ exists because the set of rotations fixing $\pm i$ acts transitively on the real projective line. Now, $Rg$ fixes $0$ and $\pm i$, and therefore is the identity, so $g = R^{-1}$ is itself a rotation.

Comment: Oh, I see. I do find it difficult flipping between thinking of $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ as a plane with an appended point and a sphere. Thanks for your insights and intuition.